# Top n elements in mongodb collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I have a mongo db collection which has entried like this

```
{
      _id:
      sender:
      receiver:
}
```

Is there anyway of getting top N in sender and receiver in the collection with/without using mapreduce? I am using mongodb ruby driver.

Comment: What makes an item a top item?

Comment: Its the number of distinct count of each.I am sorry I did not mention that.

Comment: If not mapreduce, then go for 'group by'..I presume yours is not a sharded system

Comment: @Maulwurfn Mine is a sharded system.So I proceeded with mapreduce.I started writing the mapping function 'code' mapper = function(){emit(this.sender,1)} . But I dont know how to proceed.Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would check out the new aggregation framework available in MongoDB 2.2 (the next stable release).  Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

input:

```
{_id:1, name:"Jenna"}
{_id:2, name:"Jenna"}
{_id:3, name:"Tom"}
{_id:4, name:"Tom"}
{_id:5, name:"George"}
{_id:6, name:"George"}
```

command:

```
> db.unicorn.aggregate({$group: {_id: "$name"}},{$limit:2})
```

result:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "George"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "Tom"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework

Comment: It is a great answer.But the thing is I wont be able to use the new release.Can you say me how to proceed with mapreduce functions?

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit parameter associated with map reduce, but the documentation says that you can't use it with sharded clusters. Can you output the results of map reduce to a new collection and do a .find().limit(n) query on the collection? Or are you attempting to avoid a long running aggregation command, which is why you're interested in limiting the output in the first place? Or did I misunderstand your question?

input:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "sender" : "Jenna"}
{ "_id" : 2, "sender" : "Jenna"}
{ "_id" : 3, "sender" : "George"}
{ "_id" : 4, "sender" : "George"}
{ "_id" : 5, "sender" : "Amy"}
```

MR functions

```
map = function () {
    emit(this.sender, 1);
}

reduce = function (key, values) {
    return 1;
}
```

output:

```
"results" : [
        {
            "_id" : "Amy",
            "value" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : "George",
            "value" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : "Jenna",
            "value" : 1
        }
    ]
```